# Implementing asyncronous tasks recalled on time intervals

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, thread-safety

I am trying to implement a workflow that involves waiting for a task to complete in ASP.NET (C#).

A "task" is actually some metadata in a DB that is updated when it is finished. A "listener-application" would be an application that keeps interrogating that task to see if it has finished. The reason I did this was to avoid keeping an open connection between 2 WEB APIs for time consuming operations.

My question is which would be the best solution to do this?

My current implementation:

```
bool isDone = false;
while (isDone == false)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    //check if task is done
    //if it is done, the flow will exit this "while" code block
}
```

Previous implementation that I discarded because, as far as I know, blocks the thread unnecessarily:

```
bool isDone = false;
while (isDone == false)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

    //check if task is done
    //if it is done, the flow will exit this "while" code block
}
```

Is my current implementation correct? Does it blocks the current thread? (which I want to avoid)

Comment: In general if you dont want to wait for a longer function to execte you can create fuction of varying part, call it async way and define a callback method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.Delay` internally uses a timer. It doesn't block the thread.

Comment: If I have many threads doing that thing at the same time with approximately 120 passes through the "WHILE" block will I have a problem with the Web Api ?

Comment: @PrisecaruAlin Try it and find out for yourself.

Comment: @PrisecaruAlin Hard to say without trying it out. If your web api cannot handle the load, you can cache the results for several seconds. But don't try to solve this problem when you're not yet sure that it exists.

Comment: @PrisecaruAlin Don't forget there's still the request timeouts - at some point, the request might be terminated (depending on your implementation).

Comment: @Luaan, that's exactly the reason why I am going for this implementation. Initially, I had a simple await HttpClient - POST or GET async - that went into an API and the processing could take up to 15 mins. The request eventually timed out. With this new implementation, I don't keep an open connection between 2 apps and, hopefully, it won't timeout.